# Python: Return list of keys if current time is within the range

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

This is the program I have written to return the list of keys if the current hour is present within the range provided.

```py
# time_mapping has data in key:value pair 
# where value consists of time range in 24 Hr format.

# For key 'abc', the time range is 6AM (i.e. 6) to 3PM (i.e. 15)
# For key 'def', the time range is 2PM (i.e. 14) to 11PM (i.e. 23)
# For key 'pqr', the time range is 5PM (i.e. 17) to 2AM (i.e. 2)
# For key 'xyz', the time range is 10PM (i.e. 22) to 7AM (i.e. 7)

time_mapping = {'abc': ((6,), (15,)), 'def': ((14,), (23,)), 
                'pqr': ((17, 24), (0, 2)), 'xyz': ((22, 24), (0, 7))}


def get_keys(current_time_in_hr):
    list_of_keys = []
    for key, time_range in time_mapping.items():
        if len(time_range[0]) == 1 and len(time_range[1]) == 1:
            if time_range[0][0] <= int(current_time_in_hr) < time_range[1][0]:
                list_of_keys.append(key)
        elif len(time_range[0]) == 2 and len(time_range[1]) == 2:
            if (time_range[0][0] <= int(current_time_in_hr) < time_range[0][1]) \
                or (time_range[1][0] <= int(current_time_in_hr) < time_range[1][1]):
                list_of_keys.append(key)
    return list_of_keys


if __name__ == "__main__":
    current_hour = datetime.now().strftime("%H") # if 15
    print(get_keys(current_hour)) # Then print ['def', 'pqr']
```

Basically, if the current hour is `2 PM` i.e. `14` then it will return `['abc', 'def']`.

Well, the program works but I am not happy the way I have written it. I will be glad if someone can review it and share some pointers with me to improve it.

Thank you.

Comment: Please describe time_mapping in detail - what those elements mean and why you need them in real life.

Comment: @Reinderien, sorry I missed that. Basically, time_mapping consists of key:value pair data where `value` is a time range in 24hr format. So, for example, for key `abc`, the time range is `6AM(i.e. 6) to 3PM(i.e. 15)`. I hope this will clear your doubt.

Comment: Not really - what does the "key" represent in real life? Components of a recipe for guacamole?

Comment: @Reinderien, it can be anything, nothing specific or important.

Comment: If it's nothing specific or important, what is the point of this code existing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time_mapping` is data lasagna. Whereas it's good that you've added documentation, it's not enough - the elements are still untyped. The more helpful thing to do is represent it as a simple sequence (immutable tuple) of well-typed, immutable class instances (`NamedTuple` is easiest). Representing it as a dictionary is not useful because you never actually perform a key lookup.

`get_keys` should probably not accept a current time in hours as an integer, but instead, a `datetime.time`. It can be further simplified by acting as an iterator instead of materializing a list.

Don't hard-code for the two cases with either one or two ranges. Instead, just code for an arbitrary number of ranges.

Don't `strftime` to get the hour from a `datetime`.

### Suggested

```py
import datetime
from typing import NamedTuple, Iterator


class TimePair(NamedTuple):
    key: str
    hour_ranges: tuple[range]

    @classmethod
    def from_hours(cls, key: str, start: int, end: int) -> 'TimePair':
        """
        :param key: Passed verbatim to TimePair.key
        :param start: Starting hour, inclusive.
        :param end: Ending hour, inclusive. If the next day, implies two ranges.
        """
        if start <= end:
            ranges = (range(start, 1 + end), )
        else:
            ranges = (range(start, 24), range(0, 1 + end))
        return cls(key, ranges)

    def __contains__(self, time: datetime.time) -> bool:
        return any(time.hour in trange for trange in self.hour_ranges)


time_mapping = (
    TimePair.from_hours('abc', 6, 15),
    TimePair.from_hours('def', 14, 23),
    TimePair.from_hours('pqr', 17, 2),
    TimePair.from_hours('xyz', 22, 7),
)


def get_keys(current_time: datetime.time) -> Iterator[str]:
    for tmap in time_mapping:
        if current_time in tmap:
            yield tmap.key


def main() -> None:
    time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    for key in get_keys(time):
        print(key)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Indexing

Depending on a lot of things, it may be worthwhile collapsing the time mapping to an index sequence. This will accelerate lookup at the cost of a small amount of memory and a small amount of startup time:

```py
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import NamedTuple, Iterable


class TimePair(NamedTuple):
    key: str
    hour_ranges: tuple[range]

    @classmethod
    def from_hours(cls, key: str, start: int, end: int) -> 'TimePair':
        """
        :param key: Passed verbatim to TimePair.key
        :param start: Starting hour, inclusive.
        :param end: Ending hour, inclusive. If the next day, implies two ranges.
        """
        if start <= end:
            ranges = (range(start, 1 + end), )
        else:
            ranges = (range(start, 24), range(0, 1 + end))
        return cls(key, ranges)

    def __contains__(self, time: datetime.time) -> bool:
        return any(time.hour in trange for trange in self.hour_ranges)


def make_index(time_mapping: Iterable[TimePair]) -> tuple[str]:
    index = tuple([] for _ in range(24))
    for tmap in time_mapping:
        for trange in tmap.hour_ranges:
            for hour in trange:
                index[hour].append(tmap.key)
    return index


time_mapping = (
    TimePair.from_hours('abc', 6, 15),
    TimePair.from_hours('def', 14, 23),
    TimePair.from_hours('pqr', 17, 2),
    TimePair.from_hours('xyz', 22, 7),
)
time_index = make_index(time_mapping)


def get_keys(current_time: datetime.time) -> list[str]:
    return time_index[current_time.hour]


def main() -> None:
    time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    for key in get_keys(time):
        print(key)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`time_index` looks like

```
(['pqr', 'xyz'],
 ['pqr', 'xyz'],
 ['pqr', 'xyz'],
 ['xyz'],
 ['xyz'],
 ['xyz'],
 ['abc', 'xyz'],
 ['abc', 'xyz'],
 ['abc'],
 ['abc'],
 ['abc'],
 ['abc'],
 ['abc'],
 ['abc'],
 ['abc', 'def'],
 ['abc', 'def'],
 ['def'],
 ['def', 'pqr'],
 ['def', 'pqr'],
 ['def', 'pqr'],
 ['def', 'pqr'],
 ['def', 'pqr'],
 ['def', 'pqr', 'xyz'],
 ['def', 'pqr', 'xyz'])
```

Comment: Great! You are genius! I really want to learn how to code like this, how to think like this.